# c# how to close document inspector in excel by coding?

Tags: c#, excel

My c# winform will open many .xlsx file but everytime it will show 'Be careful! Parts of your documents may include personal information that can't be removed by the Document Inspector'?

I have tried the following code but useless

```
1. xxxworkbook.Application.DisplayAlerts = false;

2. xxxworkbook.close(0)
```

Comment: Have you considered not using the legacy COM+ based integration and instead using the office sdk that microsoft provides on nuget to edit xlsx files? It is a lot easier to use. https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/

Comment: Because this is the file downloaded from other company's website, so I cannot automatically remove it. When my winform program open this document and run, it will prompt and ask me again and again.